# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta entre dos tablas relacionadas en laravel?

Tags: php7, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-6, laravel-7

Tengo el siguiente problema que tratare de exponer.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta tabla contiene 2 proyectos que para llevarse a cabo deben ser aprobados por un comité.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
En esta tabla de comité el campo state es el estado que cada persona perteneciente al comité le ha dado al proyecto. Para que el proyecto sea aprobado todos los pertenecientes al comité deben aprobarlos.

CAMPO STATE:
1 significa aprobado
0 significa sin revisar

Pregunto:
¿Cómo hago para obtener los proyectos que en la tabla comités contenga registros con estado = 1 y estado = 0 Tener en cuenta que es obligatorio que solo se devuelvan los proyectos que contienen ambos estados y que es obligatorio que por lo menos uno tenga state = 1 y por lo menos uno tenga state = 0 ni mas ni menos. Por ejemplo, si hay un registro que contenga el estado = 2, ya no debe devolver ese proyecto.

En el caso anterior devolvería el proyecto con id 1 que cumple dicha característica.

Y esto es lo que necesito, como hago esta consulta con laravel para obtener dicho resultado. Gracias.

**He intentado hacer lo siguiente:**

```
$projects = Project::where('projects.name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
->whereHas('committees', function($queryCommittes) {
  $queryCommittes->where('state', 0)
                 ->orWhere('state', 1);
})->paginate(10);
```

Pero con un registro que cumpla con alguna de las dos condiciones me devuelve el proyecto. La idea es que entre los registros existentes, entre todos los comités relacionados cumplan con las dos condiciones.

Comment: debería colocar un ejemplo, que has intentado hacer, de lo contrario no va ser bien recibida

Answer (score 0):

Esto no va tanto de Laravel, sino de escribir una instrucción SQL que traiga los datos requeridos.

## SQL

Necesitarás una consulta parecida a esta:

```
SELECT 
    projects.id,
    projects.name
FROM projects
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        project_id
    FROM committees AS tmp 
    WHERE 
        state NOT IN(0,1) 
    GROUP BY 
        project_id 
) AS tmp
    ON projects.id = tmp.project_id
WHERE  
    tmp.project_id IS NULL AND
    projects.name LIKE '%P%';
```

Si observas, en la sub-consulta vamos a obtener los proyectos con `state` igual a `0` o igual a `1`, luego por fuera, los que sean `NULL` será los únicos con esos dos estados.

Te dejo aquí un Fiddle:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE projects (
  id INT,
  name VARCHAR(150)
);
INSERT INTO projects (id,name) VALUES (1,'P1');
INSERT INTO projects (id,name) VALUES (2,'P3');
INSERT INTO projects (id,name) VALUES (3,'P3');
INSERT INTO projects (id,name) VALUES (4,'Q4');


CREATE TABLE committees (
  id INT,
  project_id INT,
  state INT
);

INSERT INTO committees (id,project_id,state) VALUES 
(1,1,0),
(2,1,1),
(3,2,2),
(4,3,1),
(5,3,0),
(6,1,5),
(7,3,1),
(8,4,0),
(9,4,1)
;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
    projects.id,
    projects.name
FROM projects
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        project_id
    FROM committees AS tmp 
    WHERE 
        state NOT IN(0,1) 
    GROUP BY 
        project_id 
) AS tmp
    ON projects.id = tmp.project_id
WHERE  
    tmp.project_id IS NULL AND
    projects.name LIKE '%P%';
```

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | P3 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8Fgwx1QsZLE8cqZSfVup3X/0)

---

## Laravel

Voy a intentar escribirla en Laravel. Dado que no tengo experiencia con este framework, puede que debas ajustar algo:

```
/*
   Esta sería la sub-consulta
*/
$subQuery = DB::table('committees')
                   ->select('project_id')
                   ->whereNotIn('state',[0,1])
                   ->groupBy('project_id');

/*
   Esta la consulta final incorporando
   la sub-consulta según la doc:
   https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#subquery-joins
*/
$projects = DB::table('projects')
        ->leftJoinSub($subQuery, 'tmp', function ($join) {
            $join->on('projects.id', '=', 'tmp.project_id')
        ->where('name', 'LIKE',"%{$search}%");
        })->paginate(10);
```